# Extracing custom files, POM,jar transitively from maven repository

Tags: maven, dependencies

We presently have a custom configuration file in our maven repository apart from the usual jar,pom files. I would like a way to download the jar,pom and configuration file transitively for all the dependencies.

I tried to use copy-dependencies and unpack-dependencies in Dependency plugin. Both of them are retrieving configuration files (identified using classifier) or the regular Jar files (without providing classifier ). I would need both of them for my CI solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Rudraksh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task using build-helper-maven-plugin. This helped me in adding the custom artifacts to the repository.

I then added the custom artifacts as a dependency by providing the appropriate classifier and type tags.That helped in retrieving the files from the repository. The catch for retrieving the custom file transitively was that I had to make sure I add the custom file dependency existed in all the services which had a requirement for retrieving custom files.

Rudraksh